# How can I list out items in an array using a for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

Okay here goes...I 'm practicing on arrays. I can manage to pick several items from a list using with the for.Each but when it comes to the for loop I am unable to do so. In the for.each I get 3 6 & 9.

```
var numbers =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,8,9,10];
var colors=["blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "white"];
numbers.forEach(function(color){
    if (color%3===0) {
        console.log(color);
    }
});
```

my for loop code is shown below what am I doing wrong I get the result undefined everytime I ran the code?

```
var numbers =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,8,9,10];
var colors=["blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "white"];
for( i =0; i<numbers.length; i++ ){
    if (numbers%3===0) {
        console.log(numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `numbers%3` -> `numbers` is an array. This condition will never be true. In order to select individual array items use `numbers[i]%3`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var numbers =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,8,9,10];
var colors=["blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "white"];
for( i =0; i<numbers.length; i++ ){
  if (numbers[i]%3===0) {
    console.log(numbers[i]);
  }
}
```

> While iterating over for loop in an array you forgot to add `numbers[i]`

Comment: why am are we adding [i] in ( if (numbers[i]%3===0)) after numbers while in the for.each we did not add it? Still new to Js

Comment: In for loop you are accessing each element by specifying numbers[i] where i =0,1,2 and so on till numbers.length.

Comment: please read more about the loops you will get a better understanding.

Comment: you're welcome. please accept my answer by ticking it.